# Azure API management always returning 404 resource not found

Tags: api, postman, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, ibm-api-management

I have an API instance in AZURE where the configurations are as below.

1. API endpoint : corol.abpparking.domain.com
2. API suffix : myaboutpage
3. Backend Webservice URL : http://10.20.10.2:8080/api/v1/

**What works**
If i call the webservice URL directly as below for the operation GET to /about, i get response code 200

```
http://10.20.10.2:8080/api/v1/about
Response: 200
```

**What does not work**
If i perform the same operation via APIM, i get a 404 resource not found.

```
http://corol.abpparking.domain.com/myaboutpage/about
Response: 404 Resource not found
```

I could not figure our what could be the reason. Note that i do not have any basepath in the Swagger definition.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to check that your API in Azure APIM is configured to accept HTTP in addition to HTTPS. You can set this in API settings, on the same page where you set API backend URL

Comment: Thanks but that did not help.

Comment: Did you try with default APIM hostname - <servicename>.azure-api. net? I see only A record for corol.abpparking.domain.com, is it mapped to APIM IP address?

Comment: Thanks Vitalily. The issue was resolved after properly configuring the internal application routing using nginx pod proxy configuration in one of the application pod. Indeed it was an application side configuration issue. Thanks lot for your time.